# getId() voltando nulo (AWT-EventQueue-0 java.lang.NullException)

Tags: java

Estou construindo um sistema básico que auxilie nos chamados do setor de TI. O problema é o seguinte: como já está no título, o método getId() da entidade setor está voltando nulo. Vendo isso, resolvi criar uma classe de teste, que funciona sem problemas:

```
    Setor set = new Setor();
    Ubs ubs = new Ubs();

    SetorDAO setorDAO = FactoryDAO.criarSetorDAO();

    set.setNome("teste");
    set.setContato("12345678");
    ubs.setId(2);
    set.setUbs(ubs);

    setorDAO.save(set);
```

Mas quando eu passo para a JFrame é que retorna esse erro. A princípio, está nos mesmos moldes das outras classes, que estão salvando normalmente. O código que está no botão salvar do frame é esse:

```
    Pattern pattern;
    Matcher matcher;

    pattern = Pattern.compile("^[1-9][0-9]*$");
    matcher = pattern.matcher(jTextFieldIdSetor.getText());

    System.out.println("teste1\nid: "+jTextFieldIdSetor.getText()+"\nnome: "+jTextFieldNomeSetor.getText()+"\ncontato: "+jTextFieldContatoSetor.getText()+"\nid_ubs: "+jComboBoxUbsSetor.getSelectedIndex());

    if(matcher.find()){
```

> ```
>        setor.setId(Integer.parseInt(jTextFieldIdSetor.getText()));
>     }else{
>         setor.setId(0);
>     }
>     setor.setNome(jTextFieldNomeSetor.getText());
>     setor.setContato(jTextFieldContatoSetor.getText());`insira o código aqui`
>     ubs.setId(idUbs[jComboBoxUbsSetor.getSelectedIndex()]);
>     setor.setUbs(ubs);
> ```

```
    setorControl = new SetorController();

    try {
        setorControl.salvar(setor);
        System.out.println("Salvou");
        this.dispose();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Erro");
    }
```

O que poderia estar acontecendo nesse caso?

Segue o relatório do console:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at syschamados.view.setor.SetorFormView.jButtonSalvarSetorActionPerformed(SetorFormView.java:160)
at syschamados.view.setor.SetorFormView.access$000(SetorFormView.java:25)
at syschamados.view.setor.SetorFormView$1.actionPerformed(SetorFormView.java:89)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener$Actions.actionPerformed(BasicButtonListener.java:303)
at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.notifyAction(SwingUtilities.java:1663)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBinding(JComponent.java:2879)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBindings(JComponent.java:2926)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(JComponent.java:2842)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6302)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(KeyboardFocusManager.java:1954)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:806)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:1074)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:945)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:771)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4752)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:746)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:719)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:717)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:716)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:184)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:229)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:227)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:227)
at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1084)
at java.awt.Component.show(Component.java:1654)
at java.awt.Component.setVisible(Component.java:1606)
at java.awt.Window.setVisible(Window.java:1014)
at java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Dialog.java:1005)
at syschamados.view.setor.SetorView.jButtonNovoSetorActionPerformed(SetorView.java:166)
at syschamados.view.setor.SetorView.access$000(SetorView.java:21)
at syschamados.view.setor.SetorView$1.actionPerformed(SetorView.java:62)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:746)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:719)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:717)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:716)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: Pode colocar o Log do erro? Assim saberíamos onde está acontecendo a chamada com o valor `null`.

Comment: Pode marcar a linha 160 dentro do método de salvar?